# Which short command to only output the IPv4 routing table?

Tags: command-line, network

`$ netstat -nr` is great for outputting the Mac OS X IP routing tables.

However its output is long as it contains both IPv4 and IP6 routing tables.

Sometimes I wish to output only the **IPv4** routing table. I wish to use short terminal command to only see the IPv4 routing table.

My best result is `$ netstat -nr | sed -e '1,3d;/Internet6:/,$d;/^$/d'`

Can this command be shortened?

Comment: Sorry, but I just can't help myself... One should read the manual page of a given command to see all that it is capable of before trying to figure out how to achieve desired output via piping to other commands.  I'm saying this as much for myself as anyone else, because just recently I found myself in a similar situation.  I was piping the output of _lynx_ to _awk_ when there was an _option_ in _lynx_ that was doing what _awk_ was. I normally read the man pages however I'll admit I was just being lazy in this case. :)

Comment: @user3439894 I did read the manual pages multiple times. Could not find the option I needed.

Comment: I skimmed the _lynx_ man page for the _option_ I missed however at 16 pages vs. 4 pages for _netstat_ I didn't feel too bad when it was pointed out to me.  :)  BTW I was **not** the down-vote on your question.

Comment: Even now 1 month after I have asked, I couldn't remember the options, and I couldn't figure out the correct commands from the `man` pages. Luckily I have asked and that the question is still not deleted, so I can find the answer again.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$ netstat -nr -f inet
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.254      UGSc           10        0     en4
default            10.0.2.1           UGScI           0        0    ppp0
10                 ppp0               USc             0        0    ppp0
```

Comment: my usual follow-up question with network commands: why is it like this? In this case, what does `inet` have to do with IPv4? Why isn't this option more straightforward, like `curl`'s `-4` or `--ipv4`?

Comment: its straightforward - inet for tcp4, inet6 for tcp6. In times before tcp6 - nobody knows about tcp6. And now it exists for backward compatibility